# Marshaling arrays from VB.NET to COM object

Tags: vb.net, interop, marshalling

I have a VB6 program which calls a COM method, passing 2 arrays as parameters and expecting 2 arrays to be populated in response.

The code is this, where ItemIDs and ItemClientHandles are the input array parameters and MyItemServerHandles and Errors are populated by the COM object.

```
Dim ItemIDs(2) As String
Dim ItemClientHandles(2) As Long
Dim Errors() As Long             ' Array for returned Item related errors
Dim MyItemServerHandles() As Long   ' Server Handles for Items

ItemIDs(1) = "2,VW1000,word"
ItemIDs(2) = "2,VW1002,word"

ItemClientHandles(1) = 1
ItemClientHandles(2) = 2

Call MyItems.AddItems(2, ItemIDs, ItemClientHandles, MyItemServerHandles, Errors)
```

Now I would like to call the same method from VB.NET, and tried something like this to define the arrays:

```
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType:=UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst:=2)> Private MyItemServerHandles(2) As Int32 ' Server Handles for Items
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType:=UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst:=2)> Private ItemIDs(2) As String
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType:=UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst:=2)> Private ItemClientHandles(2) As Int32
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType:=UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst:=2)> Dim Errors(2) As Int32 ' Array for returned Item related errors
```

but can't get it to work, because I get an error (which I try to translate from italian):

> Can't cast objects from type
>   'System.Int32[*]' to type
>   'System.Int32[]'

What is the correct way to marshal arrays from VB.NET managed code to unmanaged COM code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved.

The output arrays must be simply declared as

```
Private MyItemServerHandles As System.Array
Private Errors As System.Array
```

and they will be marshaled correctly as Int32 arrays when returning from the call.